# What change needs to be done to .htaccess file in order to see the actual URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I've a website. Inside it's web root folder `.htaccess` file is present which contains the rules for hiding the actual URL and generating the pretty URLs.

But I want to see the actual URL i.e. how the request is going to the server, what parameters are being sent to which file on the server?

For this I don't know what changes needs to be done to the `.htaccess` file. Can someone please guide me in this regard?

For clear understanding of my issue please refer the code below present in `.htaccess` file :

```
######################################
## [PHPFOX_HEADER]
##
## @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
## @author          Raymond Benc
## @package         PhpFox
## @version         $Id: htaccess.txt 5866 2013-05-10 09:06:38Z Raymond_Benc $
######################################

# Options -Indexes
# Options -Multiviews

# Header unset Pragma
# FileETag None
# Header unset ETag

# URL Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #
    #  Full path to your site
    #
    RewriteBase /

    # Rename Photo Names
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)_([0-9]*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3_$5.$6
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3.$5 

    # 301 redirect if missing www.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.% {HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # 301 redirect if missing trailing slash
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    #
    #  Rules
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?do=/$1

    # Image Access Protection
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/(.*)\.(.*)$ static/image.php?file=$1&ext=$2
</IfModule>

# Modify Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive ON

    # Cache files
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>

    # Cache JavaScript & CSS
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 months"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Compress JavaScript & CSS
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Please help me in making only the necessary changes to get the Actual URLs. Though the website should function properly.

Thanks.

Comment: What means I want to see?

Comment: @j_s_stack:Due to the pretty URLs I'm not able to identify to which PHP file the request is going and which parameters are being sent into the request. That's why I want to see the actual URL and for it some change need to be done to .htaccess file rules but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: The htaccess makes an Query String from an Pretty URL and not a Pretty URL from an Query String - That means you don't need to make a change in your .htaccess

Comment: Use: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: @anubhava:Just let me know what changes need to be done to .htaccess file into answer. It'd be great for me.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is a PHP Variable and has nothing todo with .htaccess

Comment: @PHPNut: No changes needed and you have pretty much all the rules commented. Just use: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` OR `$_GET['do']` to see original request.

Comment: You can't make any Changes in your .htacces!!!

Comment: @j_s_stack:Yes, I know but since I'm making use of complex PHP framework it's almost impossible to say in which file I should use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Instead of that if I make change in .htaccess rule it will be easier way.

Comment: NO @anubhava requested URI is the URI with wich the site was called <- the Pretty URL

Comment: @j_s_stack: I know that very well. I think OP wants original URI that was in request.

Comment: We will see but i don't think so

Comment: @PHPNut: Better you provide some example to clarify what exactly your requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your `.htaccess` file that makes `friendly urls`. It's your framework or CMS that does that. What `.htaccess` does, is converting `friendly urls` **back to** so-called `query strings`.

It's always following pattern:

```
RewriteRule from-what-users-see to-what-php-sees [flags]
```

If you want to know what URL is your CMS/Framework seeing, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

> It's not your .htaccess file that makes friendly urls. It's your
>   framework or CMS that does that. What .htaccess does, is converting
>   friendly urls back to so-called query strings.
>
> It's always following pattern:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule from-what-users-see to-what-php-sees [flags]
> ```

I copied that because thats mainly what I have commented, but nice written ;)

To get the Query String use `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` at the Top of the relevant PHP Files - The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would just give you youre Pretty URL back.

EDIT: With `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` You can get the Path of the current script.

Comment: With echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; I got  "do=/profile-57/" and with echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; I got /profile-57/. Still I'm not able to get the PHP file. Does that mean it's calling the index.php file?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; then I got /index.php with the URL http://ip_address_value/profile-57/ in the address bar.

Comment: Not yet completely. I've to dive into the huge code base to detect how the data is fetched for a specific user.